# order the list of reference by lead author(ignore others), then publish year

Tags: bibtex, sorting

How to edit the .bst file to order reference by only lead author then publishing year. Most of refercence style order all the authors first.
I try to edit the FUNCTION {sort.format.names} in .bst file, but not familiar with the syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't remember the logic with complete certainty, but I think you've found the right function to edit.  The `.bst` syntax is slightly ... odd, but the key couple of lines in `plain.bst` are:

```
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    {
    ...
    }
  while$
```

(this is from `plain.bst` – many other `.bst` files are derived from this).  I suspect that, as a quick hack, if you were to replace that first line with

```
#1 'numnames :=
```

then the function would go round the loop only once, and so would add only a single name to the sort key, which would get the effect you're looking for.

---

To give you an idea of what's going on, the way that BibTeX works here is that:

1. The `ITERATE {presort}` call iterates through all of the entries that are to be processed, calling the `presort` function on each.  The `presort` function, you'll see, defines the magic value `sort.key$` for each entry.
2. The `SORT` call sorts all the entries in alphabetical order of their `sort.key$`.
3. The `ITERATE` function (which is called twice after `SORT`, in `plain.bst`) then runs through each of the entries again, this time in their sorted order.  The `ITERATE{call.type$}` call is what actually writes out the `.bbl` file, since it calls the function `article`, or `inproceedings`, or whatever, as appropriate.

The authoritative documentation for this is in the file `btxhak.pdf`, which might be on your system already, or which you can find [at CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/doc/).

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer is so clear and it does works perfectly.

Comment: (just by the way, if you do make such a change to your `.bst` file, be sure to rename the file, or things could get terribly confusing...)